# BASH: How to start a dialog with another item than the first

Tags: shell

Advise someone how to start a dialogue automatically marked with item 2?
Thank you

```
dialog --menu "MENU" 50 160 50\
      "1" "Item-1" \
      "2" "Item-2" \ #marked the start
      "3" "Item-3"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
dialog --default-item "2" --menu "MENU" 50 160 50\
      "1" "Item-1" \
      "2" "Item-2" \
      "3" "Item-2"
```

Comment: Dang, you beat me to it by 6 seconds.  :-)